# What purpose do &&=, ||= and ??= serve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, operators

I have seen this syntax in [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)v15.0.1: `&&=`, `||=` and `??=`.
But I don't know what it does. Does anyone know?

Comment: The current accepted answer unfortunately contains some incorrect information. Maybe the implementation changed since it was posted as the logical assignment operators were still in early stages back then.

Comment: @leonheess I looked over it but don't see anything wrong, could you point out what exactly is incorrect? Thanks

Comment: @CertainPerformance Compare the equivalent section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment) or in my answer with your "equivalent code".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the new [logical assignment operators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment). They're similar to the more familiar operators like `*=`, `+=`, etc.

`someVar &&= someExpression` is roughly equivalent to `someVar = someVar && someExpression`.

`someVar ||= someExpression` is roughly equivalent to `someVar = someVar || someExpression`.

`someVar ??= someExpression` is roughly equivalent to `someVar = someVar ?? someExpression`.

I say "roughly" because there's one difference - if the expression on the right-hand side isn't used, possible setters are not invoked. So it's a bit closer to:

`someVar &&= someExpression` is like

```
if (!someVar) {
  someVar = someExpression;
}
```

and so on. (The fact that a setter isn't invoked is [unlikely](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment#semantics) to have an effect on the script, but it's not impossible.) This is unlike the other traditional shorthand assignment operators which *do* unconditionally assign to the variable or property (and thus invoke setters). Here's a snippet to demonstrate:

```js
const obj = {
  _prop: 1,
  set prop(newVal) {
    this._prop = newVal;
  },
  get prop() {
    return this._prop;
  }
};

// Setter does not get invoked:
obj.prop ||= 5;
```

`??`, if you aren't familiar with it, is the nullish coalescing operator. It will evaluate to the right-hand side if the left-hand side is either `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Mozilla suggests &&= is slightly different than the simplification you posed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment, but its not too big of a difference.

Answer (score 12):

Those are called **Logical Assignment Operators** and there are three in total:

1. [Logical AND assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment) (`&&=`)
2. [Logical OR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) (`||=`)
3. [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) (`??=`)

Fundamentally they all do the same: The logical operators `&&`, `??` and `||` in front of the `=` as in `x logical-operator= y` can be rewritten as `x logical-operator (x = y)`. Their only purpose is to replace more verbose code:

1. `x &&= y` does nothing if x is *not truthy* and changes x's value to y if x is *truthy*. It is the same as:

   ```
   if (x) {
     x = y 
   }
   ```
2. `x ||= y` does nothing if x is *truthy* and changes x's value to y if x is *not truthy*. It is the same as:

   ```
   if (!x) {
     x = y 
   }
   ```
3. `x ??= y` does nothing if x is *not nullish* and changes x's value to y if x is *nullish*. It is the same as:

   ```
   if (x === null || x === undefined) {
     x = y 
   }
   ```

Here are some examples to further your understanding of these:

```
const y = 'other value'

let def   = 'initial'    // truthy value
let zero  = 0            // not truth value
let undef = undefined    // nullish value

def   &&= y    // def = 'other value'
zero  &&= y    // zero = 0
undef &&= y    // undef = 'undefined'

def   ||= y    // def = 'initial'
zero  ||= y    // zero = 'other value'
undef ||= y    // undef = 'other value'

def   ??= y    // def = 'initial'
zero  ??= y    // zero = 0
undef ??= y    // undef = 'other value'
```

Answer (score 1):

`a = a || b` is equivalent to `a ||= b` => if `a` is true, `a` return but if `a` is false `b` return.

`a = a && b` is equivalent to `a &&= b` => if `a` is true, `b` return but if `a` is false `a` return.

`a = a ?? b` is equivalent to `a ??= b` => if `a` just is `null` or `undefined`, `b` return but if `a` is true `a` return.

> note: `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `NaN` are false

examples:

```
let a = -22
const b = false

a &&= b
console.log(a)   // false
```

```
let a = 0
const b = 'hello'

a ||= b
console.log(a)   // hello
```

```
let a = false
let b = true

a ??= b
console.log(a)   // false
```

```
let a = null
let b = true

a ??= b
console.log(a)   // true
```

If you do not understand, read it again!